UWP custom virtualized listview
I'm trying to recreate a listview with virtualization to get deeper understanding of how listview works. For this I'm creating a custom panel. When the listview items are arranged vertically I need to know the panel height. Suppose if the items are of same height then I can find the height of panel as ItemsSource.Count * itemHeight. If the items are of varying height how can i set the height of panel without computing the height of all the individual items.
Also when all items are of same height then I can scroll to an item based on the item's index in ItemsSource (ie) index * itemheight will give the position of the item in the panel. In case of varying height how can I find this position. Please guide. Thanks

You don't need an "index" to scroll an item into view; you just need the item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview?view=winrt-26100

@GerrySchmitz I think u didn’t understand my question.

"I can scroll to an item based on index". "How can I find this position if the height varies?" My "comment" was you don't need to know the index / position; you can scroll "to the ITEM". You didn't "understand" my answer.

I mentioned that I’m trying to recreate a listview with custom panels. Do you think the comment u made makes any sense?

It seems you are trying to create behaviour that is "free" ... And I was showing how. Your "custom panel" sounds like a data template. Or, it's the "items panel". You're not clear on any point.

I know that behaviour is free. And I have clearly mentioned that I’m trying to do this for learning purpose.

Have you tried YoursListView.ScrollIntoView(YourItemSource[index]);? It navigates according to the index, even if each item has a different height.

@JunjieZhu-MSFT Listview will have "ScrollIntoView" as inbuilt method. But i'm trying to recreate the ListView in this case I need to have my own implementation of the "ScrollIntoView" for which I think I need to know the 'y' position of the item in the custom panel.

OK, I understand. It is recommended to use VirtualizingStackPanel  in ItemsPanelTemplate. After using VirtualizingStackPanel, it changes from Physical scrolling to Logical scrolling. This will eliminate the effect of height differences.
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <VirtualizingStackPanel Loaded="ItemsStackPanel_Loaded"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>


private void ItemsStackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = YourListView.GetScrollViewer();
    scrollViewer.VerticalSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.OptionalSingle;
    scrollViewer.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged; ;
}

private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var elemnt = (sender as ScrollViewer);
    if (elemnt != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Scrollable Height : {elemnt.ScrollableHeight} Scrolled Height {elemnt.VerticalOffset}");
    }
}

//a sample which scroll into 8 logically
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = AuthorGroupsListView.GetScrollViewer();

    scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, 8, null, true);

}

